# How to use Amazon SNS api with c

Tags: c, amazon-web-services, borland-c++, aws-api-gateway

I have not been able to find documentation on how to use Amazon SNS API from just c.  Can someone point me in the right direction?   Is there a c build of the API or do I build from source? If so, how?

I intend to use it with borland c++ compiler from command line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/

Comment: Your question says C but you mention using a C++ compiler - which language are you looking to use?

Comment: It is really just c.  Borland c++ compiler compiles c code as well.

Answer (score 1):

As per the AWS API below documentation link I think API for AWS are not available for C.
May be below link may help you
https://aws.amazon.com/tools/

Answer (score 0):

AWS does not have a c SDK; however, you can find C++ examples in this Github repo - https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/cpp/example_code/sns